# Difference between sentences starting with "don't you...'' and "do(did) you..."

Tags: expressions

"Look, some buses are coming this way, don't you see them?"

"Look, some buses are coming this way, did you see them?"

What is the difference between them?

Context:

I was doing some translation from English to Chinese. As I compared my translated version with that in the answer key, they turned out to be quite different.

At first, I thought the sentence “Look, some buses are coming this way, don't you see them?” meant something to the effect that "I saw the buses coming, so I thought you did, too".

More, similar structures:

"It's getting dark, don't you think it's going to rain?" (do you think...?)

"Can't you see that our city is growing more prosperous?" (Can you see...?)

Any answer would be appreciated...

Comment: You are correct that it expresses surprise that the other person doesn't seem to be reacting as you are. They seem not to have noticed the buses; they haven't brought a raincoat with them; they have suggested that the city is still poor.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Not really, but thank you!

Comment: At face value, "Look, some buses are coming this way – don't you see them?", while totally grammatical and punctuated acceptably, sounds highly improbable. "Look, some buses are coming this way – can't you see them?" is far more likely (in a mist, or when the buses are tiny specks on the horizon). // "Look, some buses are coming this way ...  did you see them?" is likely when your neighbour turns to look just as they disappear behind a line of trees. // "Can you see that our city is growing more prosperous?" is solicitous, while "Can't you see that ...?" is either pedantic or aggressive.

Answer (score 0):

The combination of "Look, some buses are coming this way" which is an instruction (Look) combined with the fact that the buses are coming (and can be seen) at the present moment with "did you see them?" which is in the past tense means that the two parts of the sentence have verbs in different tenses.

This can be correct under some circumstances but this is not one of them in my opinion. "Look, some buses are coming this way, don't you see them?" is correct and does, as you say, express some surprise that the other person has not reacted to their appearance.

The forms which do not express surprise but just draw attention to the buses are "Look, some buses are coming this way, *do* you see them?" and the more common "Look, some buses are coming this way, *can* you see them?". In these cases the tenses are consistent.

The use of the negated form of the verb, can't (or in archaic speech "can you not" or "cannot you") in the first example expresses a degree of surprise or even incredulity that the other person does not perceive things as the speaker does.

Other similar forms are "don't you think that", "aren't you aware that" and so on. The form is also used to express surprise that someone lacks a skill, or posession; or that they do not enjoy or participate in some activity; or that they do not have a given status. For instance "Can't you swim?", "Don't you have a smartphone?", "Don't you play football?", "Aren't you married?".

The last four are different from the simple, neutral question which just asks for information without carrying a value judgement. The neutral versions of the last four are: "Can you swim?", "Do you have a smartphone?", "Do you play football?" and "Are you married?"

The tense of the verb has nothing to do with the degree of surprise, the same thing would apply to "Didn't you go to university?" (value judgement and surprise) and "Did you go to university?" (a simple request for information with no preconception or value judgment).

Comment: Thank you. Your answer has cleared most of my confusion. As you mentioned, "Can't/don't you" forms and the archain forms both express surprise. Could you tell me which expresses the stronger surpise, because to the ear of a non-native English speaker, the "can you not" form sounds to contain the least degree of judgement.

Comment: @1Tom There is no difference in emphasis. The different forms relate to the different questions being asked. "Can/can't you?" relates to abilities and skills, "Do/don't you?" relates to activities, habits and preferences, "Are/aren't you?" relates to status and identity. The same applies to any others I've not included. Any degree of surprise or scorn included in _n't_ forms can only be determined by context and vocal inflection when spoken.